# XLDeploy vestion and java version missmatch

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, xl-deploy

I have added xldeploy manve plugin version 6.0.0 to maven pom file in order to create a dar file.

```
 <version>2.4.3</version>
<name>Dar Format</name>
<url>http://www.xebialabs.com</url>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.xebialabs.xldeploy</groupId>
            <artifactId>xldeploy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>

            <extensions>true</extensions> <!-- tells maven the plugin contains extensions -->

            <configuration>

                <username>${deployit.username}</username>
                <password>${deployit.password}</password>
                <serverAddress>${deployit.server}</serverAddress>

                <deploymentPackageProperties>
                    <!-- Enter any deployment package level properties as <property>value</property> -->
                    <!--<orchestrator>default</orchestrator>-->
                    <satisfiesReleaseNotes>true</satisfiesReleaseNotes>
                </deploymentPackageProperties>
                <deployables>

                    <was.Ear name="example-service" groupId="com.example" artifactId="example-service">
                        <scanPlaceholders>false</scanPlaceholders>
                        <virtualHostName>default_host</virtualHostName>
                    </was.Ear>




                    <file.File name="config" fileUri="maven:com.example.config:app:properties:1.0.0" >
                        <targetPath>/server/path/</targetPath>
                        <targetFileName>app.properties</targetFileName>
                        <createTargetPath>true</createTargetPath>
                    </file.File>

                </deployables>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-id</id>
                    <!-- change to deploy-->
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>import</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I build maven Project(mvn clean install), Following exception occurs.

```
 INFO] --- xldeploy-maven-plugin:6.0.0:generate-deployment-package (default-generate-deployment-package) @ branch-portfolio-service-dar ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.xebialabs.deployit.maven.GenerateDeploymentPackageMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.xebialabs.deployit.maven.GenerateDeploymentPackageMojo not present
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/xebialabs/deployit/maven/GenerateDeploymentPackageMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:139)
        ... 42 more
```

it seems it is a java version problem. I have checked java version on compile machine.

```
mvn -version    
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: C:\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
```

When I remove xl deploy maven plugin Project is being compiled succesfully. So, It seems xl-deploy-plugin is not working properly with java7. But, When I checked documentation, it says xl-deploy-maven-plugin is worked with java7. Do you have any explanation for this, may Some dependencies of xl-deploy-plugin cause this.

[xldeploy-maven-plugin-6.0.0 Documentaion](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.x/index.html)

Comment: It will not work with JDK 7 cause it requires JDK 8 see https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.x/plugin-info.html

Comment: I could not find this documentation. You can resend it as an answer to this question so I can accept.